# how I display the list of images with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I put the data in a datahotels variable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsdtD.png)

Comment: Please clarify more, since the given us unclear at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have the link of the folder on server where the images are stored in,
then you put the link and bind the image name in image src attribute for example,

```
<ion-grid> 
 <ion-row *ngFor="let image of Images">
  <img [src]="'ImagesLink'+ image"/>
 </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```